# Get access to variables from the redis container

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-pod

I create secret redis-secret with following command.

```
kubectl create secret generic redis-secret --from-literal=password=0123456
```

After that I create pod **secrets-via-file**, using the **redis** image, which mounts secret name **redis-secret** at /secrets.

```
kubectl run secret-via-file --image=redis --dry-run=client -o yaml > pod.yaml
```

I edited the create **pod.yaml** file.

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: secret-via-file
  name: secret-via-file
spec:
  containers:
  - image: redis
    name: secret-via-file
    volumeMounts:
    - name: redis-secret
      mountPath: /secrets
  volumes:
  - name: redis-secret
    secret:
      secretName: redis-secret
```

I created second pod name **secret-via-env**, using the **redis** image, which exports **password** as **PASSWORD**.

```
kubectl run secret-via-env --image=redis --dry-run=client -o yaml > pod2.yaml
```

I edited the **pod2.yaml** file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: secrets-via-env
  name: secrets-via-env
spec:
  containers:
  - image: redis
    name: secrets-via-env
    env:
      - name: PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: redis-secret
            key: password
```

I connect to the pod **secrets-via-env** with following command.

```
kubectl exec -it secret-via-file -- redis-cli
```

I try to verify if the secret is mounted to the pods. In the second pod I want to use the variable PASSWORD to retrieve the assigned value(0123456). I used the command below but it does not work.

```
SECRET GET PASSWORD
```

Comment: inside the container if you do `echo $PASSWORD` what do you see?

Comment: Here is the output "$PASSWORD".

Comment: can you add the content of redis-secret

Comment: The content is password=0123456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tried as below. i see the PASSWORD secret is getting listed as env inside pod

```
# create secret
kubectl create secret generic redis-secret --from-literal=password=0123456

# create pod
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: secrets-via-env
  name: secrets-via-env
spec:
  containers:
  - image: redis
    name: secrets-via-env
    env:
    - name: PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: redis-secret
          key: password

# check PASSWORD secret
master $ kubectl exec -it secrets-via-env sh
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
# echo $PASSWORD
0123456
```

```
# from first pod
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: secret-via-file
  name: secret-via-file
spec:
  containers:
  - image: redis
    name: secret-via-file
    volumeMounts:
    - name: redis-secret
      mountPath: /secrets
  volumes:
  - name: redis-secret
    secret:
      secretName: redis-secret

controlplane $ kubectl exec -it secret-via-file sh
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
# ls -l /secrets
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 22 09:45 password -> ..data/password
# cat /secrets/password
0123456#
```